# The cardview evalation isn't working in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-cardview

I can not understand why the elevation of cardview does not work, I have researched many topics and told me to add:

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

However it did not work, even good work, however only predecessors lollipop devices, for example those screenshots, working ok on devices before the lollipop:

[image: Android 4.1.2]

[image: Android Lollipop]

My recyclerview column layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activities.Inicio$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="#ededed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_posto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="#403232" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Posto: Sao Jose dos campos"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_posto"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt_nomePosto"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txt_nomePosto"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="0" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout6">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_info_3"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="18:00"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_info3" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_info_2"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_today"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="14/04/2015"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_info2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="clique para obter mais detalhes"
                android:id="@+id/txt_detalhes"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_nomePosto"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_detalhes"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_info_1"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Usado"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_info1" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your `cardElevation` is set to `0dp`, and you're wondering why you have no elevation?

Comment: Hey, I had tried this before, I used java in the method to add, the more I forgot, anyway even with that it does not yet work: /
I updated to:

`card_view:cardElevation="2dp"`

Comment: Try to add card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" and remove card_view:cardElevation="2dp". I have a cardview set like I said and it is working fine

Comment: @GuilhermeP I tried, but not worked :c

Comment: Damn it.. I did not even set any elevation in my cardview and it works fine in all versions :(

Comment: Can you show me the version of cardview?

Comment: I'm using `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'`

Comment: I was using v7:23.1.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104592/discussion-between-helio-soares-junior-and-guilherme-p).

Comment: Using java i got it :)
in adapter i used `setUseCompatPadding`, and `setCardElevation`
the result:

[link](http://i.imgur.com/6duQZE8.png)

Comment: Cool. Share it as answer... It may help people in the future... You can answer and accept your own question

Comment: Very thanks :') i not know that this it's possible

Comment: Please correct the spelling in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it after using  in adapter i used `setUseCompatPadding`, and `setCardElevation` in java of adapter

For example in RecyclerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.cardView.setUseCompatPadding(true);
    holder.cardView.setCardElevation(8);

}
```

And then, the result:

[image]